# Web page updates every 5 minutes using XMLDOM

Tags: asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

I have a web page that loads a URL and does the processing using

...  Server.createobject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

every 5 minutes. It processes the data and stores it in a database.

Basically, it needs to be in a loop and run every 5 minutes and PARSE the xml.

Is there a better way to do this?

I'm open to suggestions.

TIA
Steve42

Comment: Are you doing this on the client side using JavaScript or on the server-side?

Comment: We are not using Javascript. I think we could put on server side. I'm familiar with Visual Basic script. I have some knowledge on C#. I have thought about creating a DLL or something like that as long as it could parse XML. I just did it as a web page because that was the fastest way that I thought about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. One would be to make a call from client to server using JavaScript code and the other one would be to separate that call to a web service and place it into a Windows Service or something similar.

The first option could be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(functionToCall, (1000 * 60 * 5)); // Make a call every five minutes
});

function functionToCall() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'call to your page',
        type: 'GET
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Things processed");
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("Error occurred");
    });
}
```

This is something from top of my mind to give you an idea. It might not be the most ideal solution, but it should give you some guideline.